# An extremal value distribution from monotone sequences

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Pick two integer sequences $d>a_n\geq a_{n-1}\geq\dots a_1\geq0$ and $d>b_n\geq b_{n-1}\geq\dots b_1\geq0$ where $d$ is an integer bound with following method:

1. Pick $a_n$ uniformly from $[0,d]$ and rest of $i\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ uniformly from $[0,a_{i+1}]$.
2. Do similar picking for $b_i$'s.

> What is the distribution of $\max_i\log|a_i-b_i|$ and expected value of $\max_i\log|a_i-b_i|$ as a function of $d$ and $n$?

Comment: because it is a discrete problem there is a positive probability  that the a's and b's are exactly the same, and the expected value is -inf

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of absolute difference of two uniform random variable is:
$$P(|a_n-b_n| \leqslant t) = \frac{t(2d-t)}{d^2}$$
Since $\log \ \& \ \exp$ are increasing functions we have:
$$P_n = P(\log|a_n-b_n| \leqslant t') = P(|a_n-b_n| \leqslant e^{t'}) = \frac{e^{t'}(2d-e^{t'})}{d^2}$$
Now notice that:
$$a_m,b_m \longrightarrow 0 \Longrightarrow |a_m-b_m| \longrightarrow 0 \Longrightarrow \log|a_m-b_m| \longrightarrow -\infty$$
So the final answer must be a decreasing series $\sum_{i=n}^{0}P_i$. Since $\{P_i\}$ is a sequence that decreases by high rate, we have:
$$\sum_{i=n}^{0}P_i \simeq P_n$$
And also for its expected value:
$$E(\sum_{i=n}^{0}P_i) \simeq E(P_n) = \frac{e^{2d}-4de^d+2d^3+4d-1}{2d^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment.)

I doubt there's a closed-form expression, but one can obviously find the distribution recursively. Let us consider a more general scenario, where $a_n$ is chosen uniformly from $\{0,1,2,\ldots,A\}$, while $b_n$ — from $\{0,1,2,\ldots,B\}$. Write $p(A,B,n,x)$ for the probability that the maximum of $|a_i - b_i|$ is no greater than $x$. Then
$$ p(A,B,n,x) = \frac{1}{(A+1)(B+1)} \sum_{i = 0}^A \sum_{j = 0}^B \mathbb{1}_{\{|i - j| \leqslant x\}} p(i, j, n-1, x) , $$
and $p(i,j,0,x) = 1$ for every $x$.

If I am not mistaken, the expectation for $A = B = n = 5$ turns out to be $\frac{48733041639733}{33592320000000}$, which does not resemble anything nice. The $n \to \infty$ limit might be more tractable.

Comment: denominator factored by $2,3,5$ and numerator square free.

Comment: If anyone wants to play with it, here is a Mathematica code for evaluating $p$: `p[a_, b_, 0, x_] = 1; p[a_, b_, n_, x_] := p[a, b, n, x] = Sum[p[i, j, n - 1, x], {i, 0, a}, {j, Max[0, i - x], Min[b, i + x]}]/(a + 1)/(b + 1);`